# Windows with Visual Studio 2010 on virtual machine under Ubuntu

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

Has anyone used Windows on a virtual machine under Ubuntu?

How does Visual Studio 2010 work on it?

Comment: I can't see why there would be any problems with this, Visual Studio doesn't have any specialized hardware requirements.

Comment: ok, but I just wanted to be sure

Comment: Fair enough, I wouldn't want to through all that trouble either.  Just so we know, what virtual machine are you using?  And I assume you're emulating Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed it across 60+ concurrently running VMs of windows XP in virtualbox, for computer science classes.  VS wasn't used much, mostly netbeans was used, but that was because most of the courses were java not .NET.

That said, it ran fine when I tested it.

If you have VT extensions on your CPU and they're enabled in the bios, it's not really any slower than running it on a physical windows box.  VS 20xx was always a bit of a dog on the machines I used it on.

If you don't have VT extensions, it will be a little slower, especially launch time, and some contextual menus may lag a bit at first, but it's quite usable.

Comment: what virtual machine do you use on linux : vbox ?

Comment: I use VirtualBox from a Mac running Windows 7 HP, and VS2010 runs perfectly fine, except compiling seems to take a bit longer than running it natively

Comment: I use virtualbox.  Easy to use, fairly easy to script, and the same VM can be moved from Linux to OSX easily (important for my work).